# How to approach a possible entry on a comparison between the tenses in spanish and english?

Tags: discusión

**ESPAÑOL (English follows)**

**¿Cómo abordar una posible entrada sobre una comparación entre los tiempos verbales en español e Inglés?**

Ultimamente he visto varias preguntas sobre la traducción de diversos tiempos verbales. He estudiado el tema tratando de imaginarme como sería más sencillo para mí para entender las diferencias entre los tiempos verbales en inglés y en español si yo no fuese hispanohablante nativo.
He buscado bastante en diferentes webs, y no acaba de convencerme del todo nada de lo que encuentro. Sin embargo, he adquirido el convencimiento de que gran parte de la dificultad estriba en las diferentes formas de organizar los tiempos verbales en ambos idiomas.
He compuesto una tabla comparativa, ordenando los tiempos verbales de forma creativa. He tratado de poner en ella lo que a mí me gustaría encontrar si yo estuviese aprendiendo español. Hay dos partes, una de cómo decir en español algo que conozco en inglés (12 tiempos verbales), y otra de cómo entender el significado de algo en español (16 tiempos verbales tradicionales, + 14 formas de adaptar esos tiempos verbales para facilitar su comprensión por alguien de habla inglesa).
Y ahora viene mi duda.
**¿Hay alguna manera más adecuada que otras de publicarla aquí?**

Se me ocurre que yo podría hacer una pregunta, formulándola de forma específica, y responderla yo mismo. Pero me gustaría saber si alguien conoce alguna otra forma más adecuada, o incluso si piensa que no este sitio no es adecuado para esto.

Para hacerse una idea, se puede ver [esta tabla](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gTs7fz63lm98GLARPmsG7HoJ-OJcYOEDWrTq7ezrVH0/edit?usp=sharing) (sin textos explicativos aún, que irían en el cuerpo de la pregunta y la respuesta.

---

**ENGLISH**

**How to approach a possible entry on a comparison between the tenses in spanish and english?**

I have lately seen several questions about the translation of various tenses. I have studied the subject trying to imagine what it would be easier for me to understand the differences between the tenses in english and spanish if I were not a native Spanish speaker.
I have looked quite on different websites, and everything I find does not convince me at all. However, I have acquired the conviction that much of the difficulty lies in the different ways of organizing tenses in both languages.
I've composed a comparison table, ordering tenses creatively. I tried to put in it what I would like to find if I were learning Spanish. There are two parts, one about how to say in Spanish something I know English (12 tenses), and another one about how to understand the meaning of something in Spanish (16 traditional tenses, + 14 ways to adapt these tenses to facilitate understanding by someone english speaking).
And now comes my question.
**Is there any other more appropriate way to publish that here?**

I think that I could ask a question, formulating it in a specific way, and answer it myself. But I wonder if anyone knows any other more appropriate way, or even if you think this site is not suitable for this.

To get the idea, you can see [this table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gTs7fz63lm98GLARPmsG7HoJ-OJcYOEDWrTq7ezrVH0/edit?usp=sharing) (still without explanatory texts, they would go into the body of the question and the answer).

---

Comment: Habría que tener cuidado con el término *tiempo*.  El inglés solo tiene dos verdaderos tiempos — presente y pasado — y el español tiene tres o cuatro (según consideres el condicional, pues su situación temporal/aspectual es un poco polémico).  Los demás «tiempos» en realidad son aspectos o modos verbales.